# MSChart X axis with fixed length

Tags: c#, forms, mschart

I want to show values (y axis) in a range of hours (x axis) from 7am to 12m, the X axis should show always that range even if I have no value for a specific hour. Here an example to clarify that:

X=7, Y (no value)

X=8, Y (no value)

X=9, Y=24

X=10, Y=60

X=11, Y=30

X=12, Y=80

To accomplish that, I filled out the empty Y values with zeros, so I was able to show the values from 7-12, otherwise I gonna show only the values from 9-12.

But now, it is causing me problems. So my question is, is there any way that I can keep showing the range from 7-12 even if I have no Y values in the beginning like the above example?

I use: SeriesChartType.Column;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 7;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 12;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answer from @Somebody: if you don't have a value for a certain point, you must put a "NaN" value there, anyway if you want that point to be rendered:

```
double emptyYvalue = double.NaN;
```

Use this value for the Y value in your data binding structure.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question fully, but first you should use DateTime types for your chart not ints, then Date.Hour. The wonderful MSChart will then fill in the x-axis gaps and this also enables you to use all the chart's datetime functions to assign ranges etc.